# CSS media query device-aspect-ration not woking on 16/9

Tags: html, css, media-queries, screen-resolution

I have a page that the image is cut off on a 16/9 screen. I am using a media query to try to shift the position of the image for devices with that aspect ratio, but it is not working. I have a laptop with a 1366x768 (16/9) connected to another display with a 1680x1050 (16/10) resolution. I know that the media query is correct because if I change it to 16/10 instead of 16/9 the changes are made on the larger monitor.

Any idea why this might not be working? I feel like I have tried everything.

Thanks!

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .post-87 .content-container {
         background-position:50% -200px !important; 
}
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to move an image based on aspect ratio?

Comment: JSFiddle or an active link would be helpful.

Comment: Here is the live site. It is still in early stages so I know that it is sloppy. http://s416809079.onlinehome.us/ The question above is about the first large background image. On 16/9 screens the people in the image are cut off. If I move it up it looks great, but on less widescreen displays it looks bad.

Comment: My advice would be not to use fixed pixel values in positioning bg images but rather use left or right or percentage values.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely because 1366x768 isn't quite 16/9.  1366 / 16 = 85.375 and 768 / 9 = 85.333.  The greatest common factor of 1366 and 768 is 2, so the exact aspect ratio is 683/384.  You probably could add a media query to handle this case and fix your issue.